# How do you send mail to Undisclosed Recipients?

Tags: mail.app

Not something I really ever need to do often, but just how ***do*** you send to Undisclosed Recipients in Mail.app

I've seen them arrive looking like this -
[image]
but never figured out how I might do it myself

Previously, I've sent to myself, then everybody else as BCC, but is that really the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way to do it, yes. You can even leave the To: part empty which then will result in `Undisclosed recipients:`.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, ty - no To, no CC, **only** BCC & I get that header.